# How to export from sweet.js?

Tags: javascript, github, sweet.js

I want to create a new macro command in JS for my project and I heard about sweet.js.
After I was reading about that a little bit I found [this page](https://github.com/mozilla/sweet.js/wiki/modules) that explain how to export your commands, but I didn't really understand the Github system and I always see commands with syntax like that: `$ sjs --module ./macros.js  my_sweet_code.js` and I can't figure out where I'm supposed to run those commands. So if someone can explain how to use this library and how to run github commands in general I will be glad.

P.S: I saw sweet.js is a mozilla library, it means that it works only on FF? Ff yes, is there any solution for all the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `sjs --module ./macros.js my_sweet_code.js` needs to be run on the command line on a system that has node.js and sweet.js installed. You can install node from [here](http://nodejs.org/) and once that's installed you can use the `npm` command on the command line to installed sweet.js: `npm install -g sweet.js`. With sweet.js installed you can then use the `sjs` command to compile code.

Also, sweet.js is a Mozilla project it but works everywhere.